# Burns' "To a mouse" - what species of mouse?

Tags: zoology

What's the most likely mouse species Robert Burns is referring to in his poem "To a Mouse, on Turning Her Up in Her Nest with the Plough".

Burns farmed near Ayr, which is on the Firth of Clyde in Scotland. So the mouse of his poem would have to live in that area in the late 18th century. The creature obviously was living in an open field in December in a nest made of "leaves an' stibble [stubble]". From the poem's title it appears like the nest was constructed underground. "Sleekit" refers to sleek coated as in shiny fur. A clue to the mouse's diet is given by "A daimen icker in a thrave", ie grain. According to Wikipedia: "Scotland has no population of the Edible or Hazel Dormouse, or of the Yellow-necked Mouse, and the Harvest Mouse's range is limited to the southern part of the country."

The poem is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_a_Mouse

Comment: Have you looked at the poem for more information about the mouse's habitat and behaviour?

Comment: I've tried to give a bit more information in my original question. Does that help?

Comment: Very much, thanks! Deleting my previous comments. Off topic but which word actually refers to _grain_?

Comment: "Daimen means rare or occasional, icker is one ear of corn, a thrave is a measure of cut grain". Taken from http://www.robertburns.plus.com/mouse.htm.

Answer (score 2):

It could be Wood Mouse(Apodemus sylvaticus).

[image]

Courtesy : [redbubble.com](http://www.redbubble.com/people/neilborman/works/8511176-harvest-mouse-eating-corn)